# Why reverse-proxy for persistent session in docker container?

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I am new to docker and dockerizing an existing application. The problem that I faced is that as I have multiple containers for the same application, the session variables will not be consistent across containers. So, on searching on the internet, I found one way to solve this problem is to implement reverse proxy to maintain persistent session.

One such article is:  https://boxboat.com/2017/08/03/deploy-web-app-docker-swarm-sticky-sessions/

Can someone explain how the use of reverse proxy helps to maintain persistent session variable across containers?

Comment: I dont think it is duplicate. On linked answer, there is no mention of reverse proxy. This question is about how reverse proxy solves sticky session problem.

Comment: Agree - the suggested answer does not really answer the question here.